# Can't get the select object in a JQuery widget. Require.js & QUnit is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, requirejs, qunit

I have the following code for a widget.  The widget is a searchpod.  The file is searchPod.html

```
<select class="search-by" id="searchBy">
<option value="search_by">Search By</option>                   
<option value="lastname">Employee Last Name</option>
<option value="ssn">Employee SSN</option>
<option value="eeid">Employee EEID</option>
<option value="claim_number">Claim Number</option>
<option value="leave_number">Leave Number</option>
</select>
```

I have another file called SPTest.js which tries to use that select above.  This function is inside a test function since we are also using QUnit to do unit tests.

```
define(
['../Widget/SearchPod/searchPod'],
function () {
   function checkSearchBy()
   {
       test('check if select has "Search By" text', function () {
           alert($("#searchBy option[value='search_by']").text());
           alert($('#searchBy23').find('option:selected').text());
           var expected = "Search By";

           deepEqual($("#searchBy option[value='search_by']").text(), expected, 
           "We expect dropdown text to display 'Search By' by default");

        });
    }
return {
    runny: runny,
    checkSearchBy: checkSearchBy,
};
```

I can't figure out why my .js file can't find the select by its id.
I'll put the HTML output below for those who'd like to see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CLR Javascript Unit Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/qunit.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/Report.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/GlobalReportStyles_10_css.css" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/qunit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            QUnit.config.autostart = false;
        </script>
        <script data-main="Scripts/App" src="Scripts/Lib/require.js"></script>   
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Test Results</a><button id="test">Test DOM</button></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Report Viewer</a><button id="btnSPTest">
                Test Search Pod</button></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Transactional</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                Testing is fun!
                <div id="qunit"></div>
                <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <iframe width="100%" height="600px" src="ViewReportPage.aspx"
                id="viewreport"></iframe>
            </div>
             <div id="tabs-3">
                <iframe width="100%" height="600px"  src="BuildReport.aspx" id=""></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any explanation would help.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you waiting long enough for the element to exist?

Comment: Have you tried creating a test that tests if the element exists?

Comment: Yes, and it seems that the element is not yet present when it is looked for by the code.  So what can be done? :|

Comment: Just make sure that the test doesn't happen until after the element exists.

Comment: Can you show all the HTML? E.g. how is the JS file loaded?

Comment: @Kevin - I already tried putting both the $('#id').txt and .click() functions inside the document ready function, still doesn't work.

Comment: document.ready isn't always enough. I'd have to know how the element you are testing for is being created.

Comment: @Paul - placed the html response code above.

Comment: @Kevin - that element is created when the widget is instantiated.  The widget itself is made up of a base .js file which describes its properties, behavior, and structure.  In the said structure, it loads an html file that represents more or less the widget's markup.  Its in this html file that that element is included.

Comment: `#searchBy` and the other elements are not present in the HTML file. Where do they come from?

Comment: @paul, as I explained to Kevin, the other elements are within other html files that are loaded by the widget when its instatiated and/or when its functionality is triggered :0

Comment: Ok there are a few things I think. We don't know when the module JS will finish loading, we don't know when the extra HTML elements will be loaded and we don't know when the tests are started. Only start the tests when everything else has finished.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RequireJs loading modules - Qunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615679/requirejs-loading-modules-qunit)