# ember qunit requirejs nested require load timeout

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, qunit, karma-runner

I am testing emberjs with qunit and karma test runner. I also use
requirejs for module loading.

Index route `beforeModel` hook returns a promise that calls require to
lazy load `routes/index_deps`.

`File: app/index_route.js`

```
beforeModel: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        require(['routes/index_deps'], function() {
            resolve();
        });

        // Ember.run.later(function() {
        //     resolve();
        // }, 5000);

    });
}
```

My test for index route looks like this.

`File: test/first-test.js`

```
test('hello', function() {
    expect(1);

    visit('/').then(function() {
        equal(find('h1').text(), 'Setting Up');
    });
});
```

This setup gives this error:

`Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: routes/index_deps`

If i comment out `require` part and uncomment the `Ember.run.later`
part, it works perfect.

Also there is nothing wrong with the `app/index_route.js` because it
works as expected on the browser. This error occurs only when testing.

**Edit**

`require` callback never fires, and `resolve` never gets called. So wrapping it in `Ember.run` makes no difference if i wrap whole `require` however that doesn't make any difference.

Below `here` logs but `not here` doesn't log.

```
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.run(function() {
                console.log('here');
                require(['routes/index_deps'], function() {
                    console.log('not here');
                    resolve;
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: are you testing in browser, or testing in phantomjs etc?  Are you sure in your testing suite that `require` is defined?

Comment: i use phantomjs and chrome, require is defined, i can load modules using regular `define` actually if i use `define(['routes/index_deps`])` instead of nested require, it works.

Comment: well, educated guess was wrong.  Based on your statements it looks like an issue with require and the testing framework, and not so much ember itself since you're passing off control to require... we'll have to set up a jsbin and see if we can reproduce.

Comment: seems like same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615679/requirejs-loading-modules-qunit. I guess karma-qunit handles autostart issues, i will setup a jsbin tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an educated guess.  I would have expected a different error, but maybe the promise/transition is masking it.

The callback likely isn't being run in the run loop, and as such the promise isn't resolved with the run loop running.  When Ember is in testing mode the run loop has to be manually turned spun up.  You should be able to wrap the resolve in a run call and test this theory.

```
beforeModel: function() {
    var toRequire = this.get('requireLists');
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        require(['routes/index_deps'], function() {
            Em.run(resolve);
        });

        // Ember.run.later(function() {
        //     resolve();
        // }, 5000);

    });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help, also i don't want to change my application code, for the sake of tests, since it works fine if i open up browser manually. One more hint, is if i change `routes/index_deps` to something that doesn't exist like `routes/aslkdfjals` it gives a different error, so require knows `routes/index_deps` exists, but i don't know the cause of `load timeout` error.